# How can I fix the page width to shrink to the screen size?

Tags: html, css, photoshop, slice

I sliced a PSD, and Photoshop puts the the code all in tables. I use it like that cuz I don't know much about coding.  The website looks good, but I'm running with the problem that I have to scroll to the sides (left and right) cuz I made the website 1681 pixels wide and that's bigger than my monitor.   Is there any way I can "shrink" everything using html or maybe css, so I don't have to redesign so it fits the browsers or monitor's  "width" ?

more or less.. all I got is just a table, with some stuff in it.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
 <table id="Table_01" width="1681" height="1050" border="0" cellpadding="0"   cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
    <td colspan="8">
        <img src="01" width="1358" height="59" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="02" width="322" height="118" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="sar.gif" width="1" height="59" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
        <img src="03.png" width="531" height="178" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="3">
        <img src="home.jpg" width="178" height="236" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="3">
        <img src="alke.png" width="118" height="236" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="3">
        <img src="ing.png" width="118" height="236" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="3">
        <img src="images.png" width="118" height="236" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="3">
        <img src="es.png" width="118" height="236" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="3">
        <img src="s.png" width="177" height="236" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/scer.gif" width="1" height="59" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="10.png" width="322" height="177" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="er.gif" width="1" height="119" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="11.png" width="295" height="235" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="12.png" width="236" height="58" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="pacer.gif" width="1" height="58" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="6" rowspan="2">
        <img src="13.png" width="886" height="650" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
        <img src="14.png" width="499" height="650" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="177" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="15.png" width="295" height="473" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="spcer.gif" width="1" height="473" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="9">
        <img src="16.png" width="1680" height="53" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="spaer.gif" width="1" height="53" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="9">
        <img src="17.png" width="1680" height="46" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="46" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="9">
        <img src="18.png" width="1680" height="6" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="spacr.gif" width="1" height="6" alt=""></td>
</tr>
 </table>
 </HTML>
```

or .... is there any way so it fits the width of any monitor?

Comment: This is ridiculous...

Comment: @Ivan Because, Photoshop generated HTML is never a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're talking about what's called a "liquid layout", and it's not possible with Photoshop-sliced layouts. If you want to change anything about the way your layouts display in browsers, you'll need to learn some HTML and CSS.